# Difference between classes and constants in ruby w.r.t const_get?

Tags: ruby

Why does `const_get(class_name)` return the actual class, even though `const_get` is a method that is supposed to return a *constant* of the given name.
Does Ruby just store classes similarly to constants, or is it something else?

Comment: First of all, everything in ruby is an object (Everything). So, there is no actual difference between them. And `const_get` lookup for the object, bind to the symbol you pass.

Answer (score 0):

No, `const_get` does not return a constant. Constants are not objects, you cannot return them. What `const_get` *does*, is it returns the object that the constant *points to*. In other words,

```
const_get(:Foo)
```

is more or less the same as

```
Foo
```

And if the object the constants points to happens to be a class, then, yes, obviously `const_get` will return a class. If the object the constant points to happens to be something else, then `const_get` will return something else.

```
Foo = 'not a class'
Bar = Class.new

const_get(:Foo)
# => 'not a class'

const_get(:Bar)
# => Bar
```

Comment: Hey @Jörg, could you please take a look into my question? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30236067/fire-validation-flash-message-from-within-transition-state-machine) thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In ruby, classes are merely instances of class `Class`.

```
klass = Class.new do
  # class definition
end
```

In this way, you'll get an anonymous class. If you assign it to a constant,

```
MyClass = Class.new do
  # class definition
end
```

Then you just give the class a name, `MyClass`.

The standard ruby way to define a class is only a syntactic sugar!